# Looping through a list and updating a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to create a dict for use with another python library.
I have a list of network devices that I feed into the script.  I need to grab the IP address of all devices in the input file and add that into a dict.

My issue is that the dict is only being updated with the IP of the very last device in the input file.

```
import napalm
from napalm import get_network_driver
from collections import defaultdict

device_driver = get_network_driver('junos')

dev_dict = defaultdict(dict)

with open("devices.txt") as d:
    devices = d.readlines()

for line in devices:
    try:
        device = device_driver(line.rstrip('\n'),'username','password')
        device.open()
    except:
        print("Connection error!")
        continue

for line in devices:
    try:
        dev_dict[line.rstrip('\n')]['ipv4'] = device.get_interfaces_ip()['lo0.0']['ipv4']
    except:
        continue

print(dev_dict)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'device1': {'ipv4': {'10.1.1.1': {'prefix_length': 32}}}, 'device2': {'ipv4': {'10.1.1.1': {'prefix_length': 32}}}})
```

So there are two devices it's looping through right now.
The dict ends up looking like:

```
dev_dict
defaultdict(dict,
            {'device1': {'ipv4': {'10.1.1.1': {'prefix_length': 32}}},
             'device2': {'ipv4': {'10.1.1.1': {'prefix_length': 32}}}})
```

notice how the IP addresses are the same?  device2 should be different (10.1.1.2)

```
$cat devices.txt
device1
device2
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: thats about as minimal as i can get... what else can i do?

Comment: Yeah, I should clarify - it's decently minimal, but not reproducible.

Comment: I don't get it... i described the problem.  I'm getting duplicate values in the dict where they should be different

Comment: Right but the problem has multiple components. You haven't given the input file or the code where `devices`, `dev_dict`, and `device` are defined. You need to provide them, or better yet factor them out. The page goes into more detail: [mcve]

Comment: Wait a minute... `for line in devices` ... `device.get_interfaces_ip()` ... Is that correct? If nothing else, the names are confusing. Normally you'd do `for line in lines` or `for line in file`

Comment: I added the full script - hopefully this helps clarify

Comment: Doesn't help, no. Firstly, it's still not complete; you'd need to add `devices.txt`. Secondly, I'm sure you could make it more minimal.

Comment: devices.txt is literally a text file with two lines in it.. Added it to the bottom

Comment: Great, that's the first thing you could minimize. For this example, convert it from a text file to a list of strings. Then you can get rid of the `with` statement and the `rstrip`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import napalm
from napalm import get_network_driver
from collections import defaultdict

device_driver = get_network_driver('junos')

dev_dict = defaultdict(dict)

with open("devices.txt") as d:
    devices = d.readlines()

for line in devices:
    try:
        device = device_driver(line.rstrip('\n'),'username','password')
        device.open()
        dev_dict[line.rstrip('\n')]['ipv4'] = device.get_interfaces_ip()['lo0.0']['ipv4']
    except:
        print("Connection error!")
        continue
```

this should work.

Comment: ah-ha, it does!.  is it because previously i was running the dev_dict line outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you have hardcoded the interface 'lo0.0'

"dev_dict[line.rstrip('\n')] = device.get_interfaces_ip()['lo0.0']['ipv4']"

The IP address you see is the interface of lo0.0

Comment: right, i want to see lo0 - but there should be two different values for each device